# Loop through error when checking http status code

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, error-handling, http-status-codes

I have a list of websites and my goal is to check each of their status codes. I have the following, where `urls` is a list of websites.

```
for (i in seq_along(urls)) {
  r <- GET(test[i])
  s <- status_code(r)
}
```

When I run the for loop, I get the message:
`Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :  schannel: SNI or certificate check failed: SEC_E_WRONG_PRINCIPAL (0x80090322) - The target principal name is incorrect.`

I am thinking of handling this with `tryCatch` but I am not sure of the syntax or whether to place the entire for loop in `tryCatch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `for` loop actually works fine.

```
# install.packages('httr')
library(httr)

urls <- c('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70857408/loop-through-error-when-checking-http-status-code',
          'https://stackoverflow.com/')

s <- numeric(length(urls))
for (i in seq_along(urls)) {
  
  # if URLs are listed
  if(inherits(urls, 'list')) {
    r <- GET(urls[[i]])
  }
  # if URLs are concatenated
  if(inherits(urls, 'character')) {
    r <- GET(urls[i])
  }
  
  s[i] <- status_code(r)
}

#> s
#[1] 200 200
```

(Edit after comment of the OP)
If you would like to `try` whether a certain `GET` works and, if not, ignore errors and proceed with the loop, you may use the following construct.

```
s <- numeric(length(urls))
for (i in seq_along(urls)) {

  # if URLs are listed
  if(inherits(urls, 'list')) {
    r <- try(GET(urls[[i]]))
    if(inherits(r, "try-error")) next
  }

  # if URLs are concatenated
  if(inherits(urls, 'character')) {
    r <- try(GET(urls[i]))
    if(inherits(r, "try-error")) next
  }
  
  s[i] <- status_code(r)
}

#> s
#[1] 200 200
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am still getting the message: `Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :schannel: SNI or certificate check failed: SEC_E_WRONG_PRINCIPAL (0x80090322) - The target principal name is incorrect.` . 

In the code you linked it seemed to abort after the first site, giving the value of `s` to be `[1] 404   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0` 

Is there a way to ignore the error after the first website and continue looping through the list?

Comment: I have edited the answer to also include the option to proceed with the next iteration _i_ + 1 if iteration _i_ fails.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your edit helped loop through the error.